# MATCH(x1, x2, x3). How to make x3 priority?

Tags: php, mysql, search, match

So, let's say my users can search and get results from database from 3 fields: x1, x2, x3. How can I make that x3 would get more priority than x1 and x2 and so on? Is it possible to do that? Or I need two queries for that?

Comment: What results are you trying to return?

Comment: This depends on how you setup your fulltext indicies. Do you have a single fulltext index (x1, x2, x3) or do you have 3 separate indicies, 1 for each of the fields? Or is x3 a special case that deserves its own index which you check before checking x1 and x2?

Comment: @Ryan LaBarre: Could you please answer this explaining this, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Following may help...

`Select * from <table_name>
ORDER BY 
 CASE 
  WHEN Expression for x3
  WHEN Expression for x1
  WHEN Expression for x2
  ELSE NULL 
 end`